# Animated Translated View Blocks Taps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

In my app I have a partially hidden toolbar whose frame is translated into view when the exposed part of the view is tapped.  The translation works and the buttons on the toolbar are functional.  However, the areas covered by the exposed toolbar are not tappable after the toolbar is translated to its hidden position.

Here are the relevant parts of code:

In `viewDidLoad` of the view controller that is displaying the toolbar:

```
self.filterViewController = [[LKCEventListFilterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[LKCEventListFilterViewController nibName] bundle:nil];
self.filterViewController.delegate = self;
self.filterViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.filterViewController.view.frame.origin.x, self.filterViewController.view.frame.origin.y - 60, self.filterViewController.view.frame.size.width, self.filterViewController.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:self.filterViewController.view];
```

The code to display the toolbar, part of the `LKCEventListFilterViewController` class

```
- (IBAction)openTabButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger translation = 60;
    if(!self.isFilterViewOpen)
    {
        self.isFilterViewOpen = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.isFilterViewOpen = NO;
        translation = -translation;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{
         CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
         frame.origin.y += translation;
         self.view.frame = frame;
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
}
```

Comment: Why are you animating self.view.frame rather than filterViewController's view's frame? Also, it's generally not a good idea to add another controller's view to your view without making that controller a child view controller.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks for your reply.  Your comment about the child view controller got me thinking (and reading) and I realized it was foolish of me to try and create and entirely new view controller to contain the tab bar.  I've added the tab bar view to my main view controller with success.  Thanks!  If you post something about the child view controller as an answer I'll accept it.